# 青空文庫の底本の一行あたりの文字数について

Tags: テキストファイル

青空文庫のフォーマットで底本の1ページあたりの行数や、
1行あたりの文字数についての記述方法は公式で決められているのかを知りたかったので
以下の二つの中を探したのですが私には見つけられませんでした。

青空文庫作業マニュアル
http://www.aozora.gr.jp/aozora-manual/
青空文庫 組版案内
http://kumihan.aozora.gr.jp/

ビューアに伝えるために決まった書式はあるのでしょうか？

プログラミングの話題かどうか少し迷ったのですが、
ファイルのフォーマットについての話題ということでこちらに質問いたしました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私見ですが…例えば同じ作品であっても文庫やハードカバーといった書籍の種類や出版社によって字数や行数は異なるはずです。青空文庫が集めているのは「ある会社から出版された書籍」というより「文学作品そのもの」でしょうから、何か一つに決めるより、読む方法によって読みやすい字数・行数で表示すればよい、という考えなのではないでしょうか。それを知ってどうしたいのかわかりませんが、はっきりした答えが知りたいなら問い合わせるのが確実だとは思います。

Comment: 本によっては字数に基づいて見栄えが調整されているようなので、それに合わせた表示をしたく決まったフォーマットがあるか知りたく質問いたしました。コメントありがとうございます、直接問い合わせてみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

青空文庫形式txtフォーマットにはページ当たりの行数、行当たりの文字数を指定する注記は今のところありません。
　一行当たりの文字数やページ当たりの行数は、ブラウザーの表示エリアの広さとユーザーが指定（期待）したフォントサイズで決まると思った方が良いと思います。

その上で底本のレイアウトを可能な限り維持するために、`改丁`、`改ページ`、`改見開き`、`改段`注記や、`地付き`、`地寄せ`、`左右中央`などのレイアウト注記があると思って下さい。

Comment: 参考までに、ご存じでしたら教えていただきたいのですが、これって青空文庫のサイトのどこかに書いてあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 明示的には書かれていませんね。僕自身が青空文庫形式txtからxtmlへの変換ソフトを書いていたり、ボイジャーの青空文庫形‌​式txtビューアを使った結果からです。加えて歴史的経緯を補足すると、青空文庫形式txtというのは、インターネット普及以前にそのテキストを生で読むものだったのです。その入力にあたってルビやレイアウトなどの情報を注記として拡充していったのですが、入力者の皆さんから注記を色々と提案され現在まで拡充されていったのですが、ビューアーを自作していた皆さんは下手に優秀だったせいか、自前で上手く辻褄を合わせてしまうのでビューアーを作るにあたってあった方が便利な注記というのはほとんど提案・要求されなかったというのがレイアウト注記があまり多くないことの理由です